# Compact metric implies uncountable w*-dense set

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading a proof of the following: Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. The Szlenk index is countable iff $X*$ is separable.

In the proof of => it uses the following:
If $X^*$ is not separable, there is $\epsilon>0$ and uncountable $A\subset B_{X^*}$ with $\|x^*-y^*\|>\epsilon$ for all distinct $x^*,y^*\in A$.

Since $(B_{X^*},w^*)$ is a compact metric, 'there exists an uncountable $V\subset A$ which is $w^*$-dense in itself.'

My question is, why is this second line true? (the line which has quotation marks).
Thanks!

Comment: you should ping [Philip Brooker](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/11532/philip-brooker). He is a specialist on the subject of Szlenk index.

Comment: Thanks for the kind endorsement @Norbert . The OP didn't initiate contact with me, but I do still occasionally come to math.SE and happened upon this question just now. Rather by coincidence I very recently looked at some of my own notes regarding the subject of the OP's question from when I read the same paper by Odell years ago, so I knew immediately how to answer the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are reading Ted Odell's survey paper on ordinal indices in Banach spaces :) . Anyway, here are some details that may be of assistance.

Since $(B_{X^\ast},w^\ast)$ is compact metric it is second countable, and so is every topological subspace of $(B_{X^\ast},w^\ast)$. Besides this fact regarding second countability we need two results whose proof can be found in Section 8.5 of Semadeni's book *Banach spaces of continuous functions* (this book is very handy in general). The first of these results is Theorem 8.5.2 of Semadeni's book, which says that every topological space $A$ can be written as a union $A=V\cup S$, where $V\cap S=\emptyset$, $V$ is dense-in-itself and $S$ is scattered. Moreover, Proposition 8.5.5 of Semadeni's book asserts that a scattered subset of a second countable space is countable.

Once you know these facts, the claim of Odell's paper is now easy to verify. Let $A\subseteq (B_{X^\ast},w^\ast)$ be an uncountable $\epsilon$-separated set. Then we may write $A= V\cup S$, where $V\cap S=\emptyset$, $V$ is weak$^\ast$-dense-in-itself and $S$ is scattered. As $A$ is second countable, its scattered subset $S$ is countable. It follows that the $\epsilon$-separated, weak$^\ast$-dense-in-itself set $V$ satisfies $\vert V\vert=\vert A\vert \geq \aleph_1$.