# Reflexive closure of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $E$, need there exist a reflexive Banach space $\overline{E}$ and a map $T: E \to \overline{E}$ such that any map $S: E \to X$, where $X$ is a reflexive Banach space, factors through $\overline{E}$ via $T$? This $\overline{E}$ would then be a sort of reflexive "closure" or "envelope" of $E$.

My initial thought was to look at the colimit of 
$$E \hookrightarrow E^{**} \hookrightarrow E^{****} \hookrightarrow \dots$$
but this is just a wild guess. For it to work, I'd need to know that the double dual commutes with colimits in the category of Banach spaces, and that seems doubtful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double dual does not commute with colimits as colimits of $C(K)$-spaces are also $C(K)$ but they are never reflexive unless finite-dimensional.

> In general, $\overline{E}$ and $T$ with the properties you want need not exist at least if $E$ and $\overline{E}$ are to be separable.

*Proof.* Let $E$ be [Pełczyński's universal space](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UG6zDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA434&lpg=PA434&dq=Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski%27s%20universal%20space&source=bl&ots=q0oHse4SMW&sig=UzQscmcK92lClvzTixf2E46FpH0&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkpPDsg9HTAhWRI1AKHe3WB8EQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=Pe%C5%82czy%C5%84ski's%20universal%20space&f=false); it is separable and has the property that every separable Banach space with the bounded approximation property embeds as a complemented subspace thereof.

However, there exist reflexive spaces $(E_\alpha)_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ with BAP that have arbitrarily large countable Szlenk index, *i.e.*, ${\rm Sz}\, E_\alpha > \omega^\alpha$ (already the spaces constructed by Szlenk have BAP). Let $S_\alpha$ be a projection from $E$ onto a copy of $E_\alpha$ in $E$. If there were $\overline{E}$ and $T$ with said properties, $T$ would factor all $S_\alpha$ so $\overline{E}$ would have to contain complemented subspaces isomorphic to $E_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$. This is impossible as [separable reflexive spaces have countable Szlenk index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199788/compact-metric-implies-uncountable-w-dense-set) (that is they cannot contain subspaces with arbitrarily large Szlenk index). $\square$

> There is however a silly way of producing the pair you want but it can hardly be called a *closure*.

Let $E$ be a Banach space and denote by $\lambda$ the density of $E$. Every Banach space of density at most $\lambda$ embeds into $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$, so every operator $S\colon E\to X$ may be regarded as an operator into $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$. Let $(E_\gamma)_{\gamma\in \Gamma}$ be the family of all reflexive subspaces of $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$. Set $$\overline{E} = (\bigoplus_{\gamma\in \Gamma} E_\gamma)_{\ell_2(\Gamma)},$$ which is reflexive. Suppose that $X$ is reflexive and $S\colon E\to X$. Then $X_0 = \overline{S[E]}$ has density at most $\lambda$, so there exists an isomorphim $U\colon X_0\to E_\gamma$ for some $\gamma$. Then $$S = U^{-1}P_\gamma \iota_\gamma US,$$ where $\iota_\gamma\colon E_\gamma\to \overline{E}$ is the standard embedding and $P_\gamma$ is the projection onto $\gamma^{\rm th}$ coordinate.

Comment: Hi Tomek, thanks for your answer. I'll need to spend some time understanding the first part of your answer. For the "silly" part: why can $S: E \to X$ be regarded as an operator into $\ell_\infty(\lambda)$? After all, $X$ need not have density $\lambda$...

Comment: @Mr.Chip, yes, but the closure of the image of $S$ will have density at most $\lambda$, so we simply ignore the rest.

Comment: @Mr.Chip just wondering if you need some more explanation.

Comment: Are you able to give me a reference for the definition of Szlenk index?

Comment: @Mr.Chip https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.06997.pdf

Comment: I think colimits do commute, though this wouldn't contradict what you're saying. Correct me if I'm wrong but $\lim( E_\alpha)^\ast=\lim Hom(E_\alpha, \mathbb{C})=Hom(\lim E_\alpha)=(\lim E_\alpha)^\ast$, since $Hom$ is adjoint right?  Then it would follow by taking the double dual...
EDIT:Added a bracket for clarity.